# Add a column in the dataset which contains the total number of cast in that particular movie or Tv-Show

Tags: python, pandas, string, numpy, dataset

I have just started my work on pandas. Currently I'm working on a dataset of NETFLIX.

In this dataset I want to add a new column which contains the total number of cast members in that particular movie or tv show. I can calculate the cast individually but I want to calculate all of them. Can someone help me to write this code ?

[NETFLIX.CSV FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9in2.png)

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
def set_cast(val):
    for i in df['cast']:
        if val== "None":
            return 0
        else:
            return len(df.loc[i,'cast'].split(', '))
df['num_of_cast'] = df['cast'].apply(set_cast)
```

That's how I'm trying to add number of cast in a new column but it's not working...The dataset contains 8807 rows so adding each of it individually is not possible for me.

Need a solution for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there

When you `apply` a function to a `pd.Series`, it is applied to each individual element of the series

So try this:

```
def set_cast(val):
    if val is None:
        return 0
    if val == 'None':
        return 0
    return len(val.split(', '))
df['num_of_cast'] = df['Cast'].apply(set_cast)
```